# How do I pivot a DataFrame correctly?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, unique

This is my first post on stack overflow, so apologies in advance for making mistakes in asking this question.

I am trying to pivot a DataFrame but I am struggling with understanding how it should be done properly, accounting for changes in values. I am a beginner in Python and Pandas.

The dataset I am using can be found here: https://www.kaggle.com/szymonjanowski/internet-articles-data-with-users-engagement

I have processed this dataset to this point:[article_data df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bljeA.png)

What I would like to do next is to pivot this df so that 'source_id' will become the columns. I have done that using pivot_table method but I get a lot of NaN values. Here is a printscreen of the result I get: [pivoted data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpdGK.png)

Moreover, I am not sure whether the pivot accounts only for unique values in the 'source_id' column. For that I was trying to implement a for loop which will iterate through the unique values of source_id and store them in the pivoted DF. However, I don't know how to write that code.

If you could provide me with some advice regarding what I am doing good and what not (and some ideas of how to fix that) I would be very thankful.

Comment: Welcome to the SO :). please provide what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have duplicate values in source_id, you'd need to perform some sort of aggregation grouped by that column and then use .unstack(). That's not advisable though since you have a lot of text data that cannot be aggregated.
You can try

```
df.set_index('source_id').T
```

but I don't know if duplicate index names are allowed.